# All Powershell remote programs starting as backgropund processes

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to setup a process to allow remote installation of programs.  Basically it will transfer a program and then install it.  I can transfer the programs with no issue, and I can partially get them to start.  The problem is the programs are running in Windows 10 as a Background Process and not as an Application.  So they are sitting in no-mans land and can't be interacted with.  How can I have Powershell run a program as an Application?  With full GUI of the application popping up.

I've used `Invoke-WMI`, `Invoke-Command`, `Invoke-Item`, `EnterPSSession` and in all instances I can eventually get the program to run in the Background Process area.  The only problem is no one can interact with this and the apps don't fully run (very low RAM compared to starting the apps by hand on the remote computer, no GUI etc.)

This just starts the app in Background Processes:

```
[9Y85X12]: PS C:\Users\600161236\Documents> invoke-item C:\Dell\IE_reset.exe
```

As does this:

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Computers Serial Number?'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { C:\Dell\IE_reset.exe }
```

As does this:

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Computers Serial Number?'
#Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { cd C:\Dell;     IE_Reset.Exe }
#Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process       -filepath "IE_Reset.exe" -WorkingDirectory "c:\Dell\"}
```

As does this:

```
#Variables
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Computers Serial Number?'
$sourcefile = "C:\Dell\Support Software\Browser Fixes\IE_reset.exe"
#This section will install the software 
$destinationFolder = "\\$computer\C$\Dell"
#It will copy $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder  does not exist it will create it.
Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process  'c:\Dell\IE_reset.exe'}
```

Please pardon the hashes, I try to keep prior attempted code and notes as a guide.

I'm looking to be able to setup a script to be able to plug in a serial # and run an executable remotely that the end user can interact with.

Comment: PowerShell and WMI don't support interacting with the desktop.  [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) is worth a look as it has an "interact with desktop" switch, though I haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem a few years back when trying to write a program to auto-generate a powerpoint slideshow for our company's lobby TV. I was working with limited tools and wasn't allowed to use PSExec. The workflow I came up with was something like the following:

1. Create a task on my computer that runs the program.
2. Export that task to XML.
3. Use Invoke-Command to inject that XML into a remote computer's Task Scheduler (see [schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks))
4. Use Invoke-Command and schtasks to run that task.
5. Use Invoke-Command and schtasks to remove the task after it's completed.

In my case, I was trying to run PPTVIEW but needed it to display the program and not run in the background without UI. This workflow worked for me and I'm hoping it works for you.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting work around, I'll give it a shot!